# System.debug not appearing in logs from test method

Tags: apex, unit-test, debugging, debug

I have the below test method :

```
static testmethod void addToShoppingCart_Test(){ //Line 128
    setup(); //Line 129
    oppObj.pricebook2id = customPb1.Id; //Line 130
    upsert oppObj; //Line 131
    controllerExtension = new opportunityProductEntryExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(oppObj)); //Line 132
    System.debug('#### Available products are '+ controllerExtension.AvailableProducts.size()); //Line 133
    controllerExtension.toSelect = controllerExtension.AvailableProducts[0].Id; //Line 134
    controllerExtension.addToShoppingCart(); //Line 135
    System.assert(controllerExtension.shoppingCartList.size()>=1); //Line 136
     //Line 137
} //Line 138
```

In the below debug log screenshot, we can see that it jumped from constructor exit on line 132 to Line 135..I don't know why my debug statement on line 133 is not displayed

[image]

Here are my debug log levels:

[image]

Could somebody please help me on why the line on 133 is not displayed?

**EDIT:**

As per sfdcfox, when I checked the log found this line `*** Skipped 399972 bytes of detailed log`

Comment: Was the log ~2MB in size? If so, it may have been truncated out of existence.

Comment: I see the size as '1,904,212' bytes in debug logs.

Comment: When you download it, you'll see "skipped X bytes of log" or some such somewhere in the middle. Most likely it was truncated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make sure your logging messages are seen, use LoggingLevel.ERROR in your debug statement:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, **message**);
```

It would also help to reduce the logging level on other levels down to the minimum level to reduce log size output.

Comment: Actually my test is not failing but I want to see the debug. So is there any way to see the debug rather than setting the debug to print only on error?

Comment: The LoggingLevel only dictates *at which level* the logs appear in. The default is LoggingLevel.DEBUG, which will be omitted when the log is too big. ERROR level logs will (almost) never be truncated.